# Python flask request returns undefined values

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I want to pass array to Python Flask but I got empty result or b'undefined=&undefined=&undefined='. Here is my code 
Javascript

```
var test = [1, 2, 3];
  $.ajax({
        url: '/table',
        data : test,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

and Python code

```
app.route('/table', methods = ['POST'])
def table():
    #print(request.values)
    print(request.get_data())
    return 'got this'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `JSON` to send back values that are arrays, objects, etc in javascript:

```
var test = [1, 2, 3];
$.ajax({
    url: '/table',
    data : {'payload':JSON.stringify(test)},
    type: 'get',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Then, in the app:

```
import json
@app.route('/table')
def table():
  _result = json.loads(flask.request.args.get('payload'))
  return 'got this'
```

Comment: strange it returns TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'NoneType'

Comment: @MrLukas Please try now. I changed the request type, as it appears that the `data` is not being passed back correctly

Comment: Now it works like a charm. I have spent 5 hours trying to pass that as POST. I wonder why it does not work but thanks to you now I can move on. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use JavaScript object and  send as content as `application/json`.

```
var test = {'input_1': 1, 'input_2': 2, 'input_3': 3};
  $.ajax({
        url: '/table',
        data : JSON.stringify(test),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

In your flask app, you don't need import `json` to load received data because you have sent content as `application/json`.

```
from flask import jsonify, request

@app.route('/table', methods = ['POST'])
def table():
  _result = request.json  # because you have sent data as content type as application/json
  return jsonify(_result)  # jsonify will response data as `application/json` header.
  #  {'input_1': 1, 'input_2': 2, 'input_3': 3}
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that I can store it as JSON (key, value) I want just pass array

Comment: If you send content type as `json`,  you dont need to load with `json`, your data will be already available as key pairs in `request.json`. Your `json.loads(__result)` is redundant.